# How do I invoke a function with a timer?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-multithreading

How do I invoke a function with a timer?

**models.py**

```
# Choices
time = [
('1', 'Morning'),
('2', 'Afternoon'),
('3', 'Evening'),
('4', 'Night'),
]

# Model
class Calendar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=time)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    conformation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class CheckAvailability(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def post(self, request):
        date = request.data.get('date')
        time = request.data.get('time')
        location = request.data.get('location')
        user = request.user

        if date and time and location:
            exists, created = Calendar.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user,
                date=date,
                time=time,
                location=location
            )

            if created:
                serializer = CalenderSerializer(exists, context={'request': request})
                t = threading.Timer(60.0, auto_delete(calendar.id), args=None, kwargs=None)
                t.start()
                return Response({'response': 'created', 'result': serializer.data, })


            else:
                return Response({'response': 'Exists'})

def auto_delete(calandar_id):
        calendar_id = calandar_id
        item = Calendar.objects.get(id=calender_id)
        if item.conformation == False:
            item.delete()
            return Response({'response': 'item deleted'})
```

When a calendar object is created,  I wanted to invoke the `auto_delete` function after 1 minute. The `auto_delete` function instantly works when the `post` function is called. The timer does not work
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to below line,

```
t = threading.Timer(60.0, auto_delete(calendar.id), args=None, kwargs=None)
```

You are invoking the function immediately without letting thread to handle it. Instead pass `arg` to the Timer like this..

```
t = threading.Timer(60.0, auto_delete, args=[calendar.id], kwargs=None)
```

Comment: The timer now works, but with some errors
`Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
`

Comment: Opps try, `args=(calendar.id,)` or `args=[calendar.id]`

Comment: `t = threading.Timer(60.0, auto_delete, [calendar.id])` --- its worked

Comment: after a few moments, the server stops with an **error**
`Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: This could be definitely a problem with `calendar.id` check whether argument is a valid one or `None`